# Error handling for the chol function in Armadillo

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

When sampling from a multivariate normal using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) in a long simulation I got `error: chol() failed to converge`. So I decided to slightly perturb `sigma` in order to avoid my simulation being stopped often with the following code:

```
try {
        R = chol(sigma);
} catch ( ... ) {
        sigma += eye(sigma.n_rows,sigma.n_rows) * 1e-6;
        R = chol(sigma);
}
```

However, this code seems to be slowing things down and I would like to avoid the error message being returned.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This question is too broad.  You state you have a numeric issue, yet say _nothing_ about your data generation.  Also, you have asked three questions in the last twelve hours, and all three are mostly answerable by reading the Armadillo docs.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel I'm using a standard metropolis algorithm in which I need to sample from a multivariate normal. I have meteorological data (wind speed, humidity, irradiation, etc). I'm asking after reading the documentation although I'm learning c++ and therefore do not understand many things, in particular debugging, etc. By the way, the code I'm using to generate from a normal is the one in this [post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simulate-multivariate-normal/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Armadillo has two forms of [chol()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#chol). The first returns a matrix, while the second stores the output in a matrix specified as an argument. To avoid using `try {} catch (...)`, use the second form:

```
bool success = false;

while(success == false)
  {
  success = chol(R, sigma);

  if(success == false)
    {
    sigma += eye(sigma.n_rows,sigma.n_rows) * 1e-6;
    }
  }
```

Whether the above converges (and the speed of convergence) is highly dependent on the starting point for `sigma`.